# AWS Cognito relation between groups (organization)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Can we managing a pool of users in AWS Cognito by creating sub-groups and manipulating the sub-groups as if we were using a relational (groups)database?

Do you have tips for managing organisations with aws?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As for tips on managing organisations with aws:

For Cognito (application user behaviour) you might be able to use groups for this feature. Note that groups are primarily designed for role-based access and not specifically for tenant separation. You probably should create separate groups for tenants, so you might be in the R_Engineering (role) and the V_ACME (tenant) group, optionally allowing rules based on the authentication provider for that tenant to assign the group. Some information on groups and fine-grained access control can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/. Also, check out this post: https://medium.com/@dantasfiles/multi-tenant-aws-amplify-cc3252c4def4 mentioning ways to do grouping.

If you are looking to manage AWS resources access for organizations, this can be accomplished with AWS Organizations.

As for manipulating all users in a certain group I can only suggest you look into the API of Cognito (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-reference.html).